# Setting database records into jtextfield

Tags: java, database, jtextfield

The problem of my code is that it can't set the data from my database onto my jtextfield. Every time I run my code, it says StackOverflowError. How could I fix this error?

Here's my code

```
public class DataConnect extends DatabaseGUI {
    private Connection dataCon;
    private Statement dataStmt;
    private ResultSet dataRS;
    private String name, address;
    int age;


    public DataConnect(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            dataCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentrec","root","");
            dataStmt = dataCon.createStatement();
            dataRS = dataStmt.executeQuery("Select * from studentrecords");
        }catch(Exception exc){
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setData(){
        try{
            dataRS.next();
            name = dataRS.getString("Name");
            age = dataRS.getInt("Age");
            address = dataRS.getString("Address");
            DatabaseGUI dbGui = new DatabaseGUI ();

            dbGui.jtfData[0].setText(name);
            dbGui.jtfData[1].setText(Integer.toString(age));
            dbGui.jtfData[2].setText(address);
           //System.out.println(name+" "+age+" "+address);
         }catch(Exception exc){

        } 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause of your problem is here:

```
public class DataConnect extends DatabaseGUI {
    //...


    public DataConnect(){
        //...
    }

    public void setData(){
        try{

            DatabaseGUI dbGui = new DatabaseGUI ();  //*****
```

You're creating a new DatabaseGUI object within a class that extends DatabaseGUI and risk infinite recursion. Solution: probably you don't want DataConnect to extend DatabaseGUI, or you don't want to create a new DatabaseGUI inside of DataConnect, or both. If you already have a displayed DatabaseGUI, then you don't want to create another non-displayed one, but instead will want to set the data of the components of the GUI that is already displayed, not a new one that you create on the spot.

Also, I have to wonder -- do you create a DataConnect object within your DatabaseGUI class? Your question can be improved greatly by your doing a bit of debugging to find out which code in particular causes the exception to occur.

Also this empty catch block

```
catch(Exception exc){

}
```

is code that should never happen. At least print the stacktrace.